# About uniformly integrability

Tags: real-analysis

This problem is from a exercise where I want to apply Vitali theorem.So I'm trying to prove that:
If $\left\{f_{n}\right\}\subseteq L^{p}$ ($1\leq p <\infty$) where $\left\{\left\|f_{n}\right\|_{L^{p}}\right\}$ is bounded, then $\left\{f_{n}\right\}$ is uniformly integrable.

I don't think this must be valid since from definition it's not easy to prove it.If not,can anyone construct some counterexample.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take $p=1$ and
$$
f_n := n\chi_{[0,1/n]}
$$
then $\|f_n\|_1 = 1$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$ but for $\epsilon = 1/2$ and any $\delta > 0, \exists n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that if $A = [0,1/n]$, then $m(A) < \delta$ and
$$
\int_A |f| \geq \epsilon
$$
so $\{f_n\}$ is not uniformly integrable.

However, if $p>1$, then norm boundedness implies uniform integrability because if $\|f_n\|_p \leq M$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$, then for any measurable $E$, Holder's inequality gives
$$
\int_E |f_n| \leq \|f_n\|_p \|\chi_E\|_q \leq M m(E)^{1/q}
$$
and so if $\epsilon > 0$, then $\delta = (\epsilon/M)^q$ works.